# Could not able to sign apk, showing error as follow

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, angular6

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

  > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key nBoard from store "F:\android\nBoard\nBoard.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

I tried deleting the keystore and generating new one but it did not worked?

used the below code to generate keystore

keytool -genkey -v -keystore app-name.keystore -alias app-name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

I expect the solution for the above error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your keystore doesn't exist in the path defined. Maybe because in the command you didn't provide the app name.

Go to build option in tool bar and select build signed apk, from there select manually the keystore. If app is not live, create a new one.

[image]

Comment: I was working on visual studio and git bash is showing different errors,

I changed the path and again run that command from command prompt and it worked.